# What is wrong when reading a string using fetch with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

What is wrong with this React method? The problem is that the "this.context" variable is visible as a String only inside this fetch arrow function. Outside of it, it is an Object. Why? And how do i get the string out of this object (inside other class methods)? (The server (JEE6/Tomcat) sends string data, not a json-object)

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("GetContext")
      //.then(res => res.json())
      .then( res => res.text ())
      .then(
        (text) => {
          this.context = text;
          this.initBackground (text);              
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log ("context init error "+error);
        }
    )        
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of your component ?

Comment: this.context is out of scope after the request sent to the server, declare `this.context` outside the method as `constant` and u should get the original value inside `then`.

Comment: Your usage of `context` is quite ambiguous: do you mean to use your own variable named `context` or do you try to use the React `context`? They might collide here.

Comment: Thank tou for answers. Seems like problem was solved only by changing the name of the variable. Perhaps "this.context" is reserved word in javascript or in react..

Comment: correct, it's reserved in React: [see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform that the solution was simply to change the name of the variable. This works:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("GetContext")
      //.then(res => res.json())
      .then( res => res.text ())
      .then(
        (text) => {
          this.serverContext = text;
          this.initBackground (text);              
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log ("context init error "+error);
        }
    )        
}
```